# Remove all metadata from PNG, commandline

Tags: png, thumbnails, imagemagick

I'm trying to create really small PNG thumbnails from JPGs using GraphicsMagick.

```
gm convert coolphoto.jpg  -resize 16x16 -colors 6 coolphoto_16x16_6color.png
```

These get down to 342 bytes,  but they seem to have a few fields I don't want,  I see these strings floating in the files:

```
EXtJPEG-Quality
EXtJPEG-Colorspace
EXtJPEG-Colorspace-Name
EXtJPEG-Sampling-factors
```

I want to get rid of these to make the file even smaller.    I *can* get rid of these using ImageOptim,  taking size to 181 byets,   but it's sort of built to be a UI-based app.

Is there a commandline tool,  something like GraphicsMagick, that can do this?

Comment: Is it photography related ?

Comment: They are photos?  Not sure this is the right place but got good help here with image processing before

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to photography. Try [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: @OneSolitaryNoob we're happy to help with image processing questions *when they're related to photography*, but general image processing questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove all the EXIF info from your photos you can use [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

The command should looks like:

```
exiftool -all= coolphoto_16x16_6color.png
```